# Generate random binary vector with equal Ones and Zeros

Tags: r, random, vector

In R programming language, say you want to create a random binary vector with 4 elements.

The constraint is that the numbers of one's and zero's have to be equal.

So

```
(0,0,1,1)
(0,1,1,0)
(1,1,0,0)
...
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You could check `?rbinom` or `sample`

Comment: Does `f` have a random shuffle function?  If so, then `shuffle(0,0,1,1)` should work.

Comment: rbinom(4, 1, 0.5) this makes 4 random numbers between 0 and 1 with a probability of 0.5 between the two elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just randomly select every case without replacement from a set containing 2 0's and 2 1's.

```
sample(rep(0:1,each=2))
#[1] 0 1 1 0
```

Always works:

```
replicate(3,sample(rep(0:1,each=2)),simplify=FALSE)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 0 0 1
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 0 1 0 1
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 1 1 0 0
```

Comment: @akrun - I doubt it. The random element will always throw up too much opportunity for cases that don't meet the criteria.

Answer (score 2):

```
sample(c(1,1,0,0), 4)
```

or generalise to:

```
sample(rep(c(0,1),length.out=n/2),n)
```

Comment: `sample` doesn't need an `n` specified if you are sampling everything. It will just scramble the cases.

Comment: @thelatemail very true thanks! I was trying to be explicit for communication

Comment: The probabilities are not even if length.out is an odd number. Try: sample(c(0,1),5,replace=T)

Answer (score 0):

**Create a random binary vector with random ones and zeros:**

```
#create a binary vector:
result <- vector(mode="logical", length=4);

#loop over all the items:
for(i in 1:4){
    #for each item, replace it with 0 or 1
    result[i] = sample(0:1, 1);
}
print(result);
```

Prints:

```
[1] 0 1 1 0
```